# Join two tables with similar columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join, foreign-key, heidisql

I hva two tables as is:

- Table *univers*:

| client | commercial |
| --- | --- |
| Axel | Tony |
| Mike | Jhon |
| Chris | Jhon |

- Table transactions

| frclient | toclient | commission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Axel | NA | 10 |
| Mike | NA | 8 |
| NA | Mike | 15 |
| Axel | NA | 4 |
| NA | Chris | 5 |
| Chris | NA | 5 |

Now, I would like to be able to have the total commissions generated by Jhon and Tony's clients, a bit like:

| commercials | commissions |
| --- | --- |
| Jhon | 33 |
| Tony | 14 |

The only element that links the *univers* table and the *transactions* table are the customer IDs, namely their names, nothing else.

How can I proceed please? THANKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.commercial, SUM(t2.commission) commissions
FROM univers t1
JOIN transactions t2 ON t1.client IN (t2.frclient, t2.toclient)
GROUP BY 1
```